# some posts being displayed as pages

Tags: posts, pages

Some posts I make (in the same category) are acting as pages, they open as page templates.

I have the following in my `single.php`

```
<div class="mainbody">

      <?php
      while (have_posts()): the_post();
      $more = 0;
         // the_title();
         the_content('READ MORE');
      endwhile;
      ?>

</div> <!-- end .mainbody -->
```

and `page.php`

```
<div class="mainbody" style="width: 1000px; background:#999;">

       <?php

        while (have_posts()): the_post();
      $more = 0;
         // the_title();
         the_content('READ MORE');
      endwhile;

        ?>

</div> <!-- end .mainbody -->
```

Any idea why?

Comment: The choice of template occurs well before those files come into play. Something else is happening but it is hard to say what. Have you added any filters on `pre_get_posts` or `template_redirect`?

Comment: Yea, I have a filter plugin that uses pre_get_posts, but I have the same things on another installation (both plugins) and no problems. Also, this seems to be working now for whatever reason. In any case, why would one post show up normally and another one not? Who knows what happened...